# Python - Remove white space using only loops

Tags: python

I want to remove extra spaces in a string using only `for/while` loops, and `if` statements; NO split/replace/join.

like this:

```
mystring = 'Here is  some   text   I      wrote   '

while '  ' in mystring:
    mystring = mystring.replace('  ', ' ')

print(mystring)
```

**output:**

```
Here is some text I wrote
```

Here's what I tried.  Unfortunately, it doesn't quite work.

```
def cleanupstring(S):
    lasti = ""
    result = ""

    for i in S:
        if lasti == " " and i == " ":
            i = ""

        lasti = i    
        result += i    

    print(result)


cleanupstring("Hello      my name    is    joe")
```

**output:**

```
Hello   my name  is  joe
```

My attempt doesn't remove all the extra spaces.

Comment: I assume this is some sort of learning exercise, since I would probably just use a regex for this.

Comment: You are updating `i` before you set what `lasti` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
    for i in S:
        if lasti == " " and i == " ":
            i = ""
        else:
            lasti = i    
        result += i    

    print(result)
```

Comment: FWIW: The bug is that when you set `i=""`, you are later setting `lasti = i`. Which means that lasti is no longer a space, and therefore the next time a space appears, your test condition is not met. Putting the `else` in separates the two paths, and leaves `lasti` set to space when a space is ignored.

Comment: @RaminNietzsche I was explaining why your code works, where the original code doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the current character and the next one are spaces, and if **not**, add them to a clean string. There really is no need for an `and` in this case, since we are comparing to the same value

```
def cleanWhiteSpaces(str):
  clean = ""
  for i in range(len(str)):
    if not str[i]==" "==str[i-1]:
      clean += str[i]
  return clean
```

Comment: Wouldn't it compare the *last* character at the 1st iteration since `S[-1]` gives you the last character?

Comment: You're right, range needs to start on 1, not 0, actually changed that for no reason

Answer (score 1):

Uses the end of `result` in place of `lasti`:

```
def cleanupstring(S):
    result = S[0]

    for i in S[1:]:
        if not (result[-1] == " " and i == " "):
            result += i

    print(result)


cleanupstring("Hello      my name    is    joe")
```

Answer (score -1):

### Just try this

t = "Hello      my name    is    joe"

" ".join(t.split())

## this will output

"Hello my name is joe"